# How can I use the same route for different paths?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's say I have a Root route with a search field and a Questions route that renders some questions. Questions loads some data in a loader function E.g.:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Questions />,
        loader: questionsLoader  
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

What I want is, when a user types something in the search field and hits enter, then it should navigate to `search?q=asd` where `asd` is the value of the search field.

What I do is wrap the search field around a form element and whenever the form is submitted, user hit enter, then i use `navigate` from `useNavigate` and pass the desired `to` e.g.: `search?q=asd`.

Then I update my `router` to look like this.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Questions />,
        loader: questionsLoader  
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        element: <Questions />,
        loader: questionsLoader
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

Then I filter my data properly based on the request search params in the loader function.

My real question is, **is there a better way to define multiple paths for a route?**

In this example I have one, but in reality I have more paths that render Questions and filter the data, and repeating code (in router) doesn't feel the correct way to go.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking since each route can have only one `path` string prop value. Can you clarify what you are trying to do or what you are asking about? Is the question really something more like "can different routes/paths render the same component"? FWIW the routing config looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, multiple paths that render the same component. IT looks fine to me too, but I have a couple more. E.g. path: 'questions/tag/:tagName'. I have to define same element and loader for all. I'm looking for some combination of splats or optional segments.

Comment: I think you'll just need 1 route/path per `Questions` "instance" you want to match and render. You can search the [github issues](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues) to see if there's a thread requesting path arrays back and pile on the want and desire. You can always try making an array of paths you want to render the same component on and map that. Do you need an example? And if so, do you mind [edit] to the post to include a more exhaustive [mcve] of the other routes you need to also  render `Questions`?

Comment: That's true, I just read that v5 allowed array of paths but v6 removed that ability.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of paths, map them, and spread them. Like this:

```
[
  {
    path: 'user-profile',
    element: <UserProfilePage />,
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot-password',
    element: <ForgotPasswordPage />,
  },
  ...[
    'verify-email/userId/:userId/verifyToken/:verifyToken',
    'verify-email/userId/:userId',
  ].map(path => ({
    path,
    element: <VerifyEmailPage />,
  })),
]
```